# Cant find Ubuntu Studio Back ports PPA after adding

Tags: sound, ppa, editing, 19.04

New to all things Linux. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 a few days ago before I knew about Ubuntu Studio. Today I added the 19.04 back ports PPA but I dont know what to do to access or apply the upgrade. Since this is all a learning curve for me and I have all my files backed up, I am considering just starting fresh again with Ubuntu Studio  19.04. Suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you add the PPA this way? : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/BackportsPPA

Comment: Yes. When the text in the terminal said Done I closed the terminal.

Comment: I'm actually downloading the release to just start fresh now but I'd like to know what I did wrong.